# How to change a value in mysql database using conditions from java code?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to change a value `Dr_status` that only contain one int even 0 or 1. So if `Dr_status` equal to 1 change it to 0 and vice versa.
Here is the code :

```
String query = "Select Bluetooth_Address FROM dr";
String str = "40D32DBBE665";//in the database I have only two fields in `Bluetooth_Address` column 40D32DBBE665 and another value 
String check = "";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
PreparedStatement preparedStmt= con.prepareStatement("update `dr` set `Dr_status` = '1'");
PreparedStatement preparedStmt1= con.prepareStatement("update `dr` set `Dr_status` = '0'");

  dbtime = rs.getString(1);               
   if (dbtime.equals(str)){
       check = "Select `Dr_status` From `dr` Where `Bluetooth_Address` = " + " " + str ;
       if(check.equals(0)){ 
            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
                    }
                    if(check.equals(1)){
                        preparedStmt1.executeUpdate();
                    }
```

I don't know where is the problem !!! please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove  `if(check.equals(0))`. `check` is a string and will never be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give +1 to the answer from @Marcelo Hernández Rishmawy.  Instead of testing the condition in Java code, do the test and the update in an SQL expression that converts 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 automatically, for the rows that match your Bluetooth address condition.

I'll also give you a tip that in MySQL, 1 and 0 are integers, but they are also used for true and false.  So you can use either of the following tricks to make the statement more compact:

```
"update `dr` set `Dr_status` = ! `Dr_status` where `Bluetooth_Address = " + str
```

This trick works too:

```
"update `dr` set `Dr_status` = 1 - `Dr_status` where `Bluetooth_Address = " + str
```

It's a nice way to simplify, but FWIW it's specific to MySQL, not standard SQL.  Other databases brands use proper boolean values, not 1 and 0.

---

Re your comment: the error is not related to the solutions above, it's because you're interpolating a string of hex digits.  You need to either quote the string, or better yet use a query parameter.

You should learn how to use query parameters in any case, because they're good for writing secure code to defend against SQL injection issues, and it's generally easier and more robust than trying to interpolate variables into SQL query strings.

See [Using Prepared Statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) at The Java Tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, but it show me this error :
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '40D32DBBE665' in 'where clause' for the two ways you have mentioned

Comment: It works now but after a small edit :
"update `dr` set `Dr_status` = 1 - `Dr_status` where `Bluetooth_Address` = '" + str + "'"
Thanks for helping me, you are the best :)

Comment: Please do remember to learn how to use prepared statements instead of interpolating Java variables into your queries.  All programmers have a responsibility to write secure code, or else hackers will continue to steal Sony Playstation account data forever.

Answer (score 2):

Use something similar to:

```
"update `dr` set `Dr_status` = CASE `Dr_status` WHEN '1' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END CASE Where `Bluetooth_Address` = '" + str + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it show me this error :
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE Where `Bluetooth_Address` = 40D32DBBE665' at line 1

Comment: @Mohannad.Z Corrected it, was not sure if the column Bluetooth_Address was a varchar or not.

Comment: Thanks for quick response :) but the same error appears :( : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE Where `Bluetooth_Address` = '40D32DBBE665'' at line 1

Comment: @Mohannad.Z Then you can try @Bill Karwin's method adding the apostrophes for the Bluetooth_Address value.

Comment: It doesn't work also but thanks anyway I'll try to fined another solution. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The line `if(check.equals(0)){` is invalid.  check is a String and will never equal 0

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this : if(check.equals("0"))
and change the type of Dr_status to varchar in the database but nothing happened !!!

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my original comment.  You have a String object named **check** whose value equals *Select `Dr_status` From `dr` Where `Bluetooth_Address` = 40D32DBBE665*.  If you print out the value of check you will see the text *Select `Dr_status` From `dr` Where `Bluetooth_Address` = 40D32DBBE665*.  Later you are checking to see if that text equals 1 or 0.  It's like you are saying does "Dog" equal 1.  The if statements *if(check.equals(0))* and *if(check.equals(1))* will never evaluate to true regardless of the databases contents, because you are comparing text to a number